# Equivalent definitions of a group acting on a group?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

I've always seen this definition of a group $G$ acting on a set $\Omega$, making this latter a $G$-set:

> Given a group $G$ and a set $\Omega$ we say a group **acts** on the set $\Omega$ when there's a function $\Omega\times G \mapsto \Omega$  such that, denoting with $\alpha^g$ the image of $(\alpha,g)$ it holds:$$\alpha^{gh}=(\alpha^g)^h, \alpha\in\Omega, g, h \in G \\ \alpha^e=\alpha, e=G_{Id}$$

In particular this definition applies also if $\Omega$ is yet another group $H$, for instance.

So far, so good. Recently, studying the group extension problem and the short exact sequence, I faced the cohomology and, trying to get a grasp out of it (even if a bit too advanced for my current group training), I came to this definition:

> Given two groups $G$, $H$ and a homomorphism $\phi:G \mapsto {\rm Aut}(H)$, we say G acts on H through $h^\sigma=h^{\phi(\sigma)}, h \in H, \sigma \in G$

I was wondering if these two definitions are equivalent and the second should be preferred to the former, when the target set is a group as well, since more coincise and using ${\rm Aut}(H)$ without the need to specify the other conditions in the former definition.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Two very simple examples: 1) A group $G$ acts on itself by (right) multiplication, which does not satisfy the second definition. 2) A group $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, which satisfies the second definition.

Comment: Where the right multiplication fails with  the 2nd definition?  The morphism would not be onto?I've never fully understood this asymmetry between left and right action

Comment: Right multiplication by a non-trivial element $g$ is a bijection but not a homomorphism, as the identity is mapped to $g$.

Comment: Can you post an answer for this, explaining why the right action Is not a homomorphism according to the second definition? My Guess Is neither the left action nor the right action  can be, so it's not clear why you chose the right One only. Tx

Comment: I chose right multiplication because your original question gives the definition of a right action, and left multiplication is a left action but (in general) not a right action. But if you're also considering left actions, then you're absolutely right, left multiplication (by a non-trivial element) is not a homomorphism either.

Comment: Tx this makes sense to me

Comment: Just to understand better since @Noobie below confused me a bit: left multiplication is not a homomorphism only when $G$ acts on $G$, or in a general case where $G$ acts on a set $X$?

Comment: Look up "Cayley's Theorem".  It's how it's proved.  Sorry to confuse you.   Yesterday I had it wrong.

Comment: Probably my confusion arises in understanding the difference between $\text{Sym}(X)$, when $X$ is $G$ itself and $\text{Aut}(G)$. May I raise a new question out of it?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4484085/1007416

Comment: @fitzcarraldo, your comment "doesn't the action in Cayley's theorem explicitly use group's operation? So, in what sense it is rather an action on the underlying set" Is exactly mine, specifically when the action Is a simple left multiplication. I can't see any explanation of that in that post

Comment: However I'm going back to Cayley's thm to understand Better that. There must something I'm missing between Sym(G) and Aut(G).

Comment: I think the point is: *if* your set $X$ happens to be also a group, *and* you have a homomorphism $G\to\operatorname {Aut}(X)(\le\operatorname{Sym}(X))$, then $G$ acts *by automorphisms* on $X$. An action *not* by automorphisms is "rather an action on the underlying set" (as Cayley's $G\hookrightarrow \operatorname {Sym}(G)$).

Comment: Yes that's clear now. For instance, talking $X=S_3$ we got $|\text{Sym}(X)|=720$ while $|\text{Aut}(X)|=6$, i.e. the six conjugations by each element. So the difference Is really big and that's why Cayley's-like action Is a lot less restrictive than $G \mapsto \text{Aut}(X)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definitions are not equivalent. The difference stays in the fact that on a $G$-set $X$ the definition of action is equivalent to have a homomorphism $$G\to S(X)$$ where $S(X)$ is the group of self-bijections of $X$.
If $X$ has a group structure the second definition is equivalent to have a homomorphism $$G\to Aut(X)$$ that is a stricter condition.

For instance consider $X=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ and $G=\Bbb Z$.
Here the action induced by $1\cdot [1]=[2]$ is an action according to the first definition and not according to the second: an automorphism can send $[1]$ only to an other generator of $X$.

However you will often find the second definition applied to groups: more generally, a group $G$ action on some object $V$ of some category will be often asked to be an homomorphism $G\to Aut(V).$
This thus applies also when $V$ is a vector space, or a ring, or an algebra!

Comment: So It could be better using the second One when the set Is a group, to my view

Comment: So in your example the second definition would send $[1]$ to what? $[1]$?

Comment: @riccardoventrella $[1]$ could be sent only to $[\pm 1]$, the two generators of $\Bbb Z_4$

Comment: Yes I had already edited It, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated,  when we have a homomorphism from $G$ to $\rm{Aut}(H)$, we get an action of $G$ on $H$.

But the converse is false.   That's consider the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication.   Then we do, as always,  get a homomorphism into the symmetric group on the underlying set of $G$, since $x\mapsto g\cdot x$ defines a bijection.  But we don't get a homomorphism into the automorphism group of $G$.  Note that $e\mapsto g\cdot e=g$, so that the identity of $G$ is not preserved (unless $g=e$).

Comment: As explained in the answer by Alessandro Cigna, the two definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: As shown above by @sTertooy, neither a left multiplication nor a right multiplication are homomorphism, so I think this cannot apply to the "symmetric group on the underlying set" neither

Comment: No you always get a homomorphism into $S(X)$, when $G\curvearrowright X$.

Comment: Even when $X$ is $G$ itself?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I referred you to Cayley's theorem.   It can be done with either a right or left multiplication btw.  Since $S(\Omega)$ is just bijections, there's no issue of preserving the identity.   The homomorphism from $G$ into $S(G)$ does of course,  because it's a homomorphism.   But that's a different point.