# About $\text{Sym}(G) \setminus \text{Aut}(G)$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484085/g-h-groups-why-not-caring-about-g-actions-on-h-s-t-phi-g-in-rmsym) post it's used $$\phi_g \in \text{Sym}(H) \setminus \text{Aut}(H)$$

Does the $\setminus$ stand for "set difference"? If yes, what this difference really represents between groups, please? I'm used to factoring groups, but that symbol is new to me.
More than this: is $\text{Sym}(G)$ bigger than $\text{Aut}(G)$ since the former is made by bijections, while the latter by isomorphims?

This could explain why we could subtract the second set from the first one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, every automorphism of $G$ is a bijective map from $G$ to $G$, but not every bijective map $f\colon G\rightarrow G$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: I think the $\text{Sym}(G) \setminus \text{Aut}(G)$ should be read as "right coset of $\text{Aut}(G)$ by $\text{Sym}(G)$" rather than symmetric difference

Comment: I see @DietrichBurde. So not fully clear what's the meaning of $\phi_g$ now.

Comment: Given that the post immediately talks about "$g\in G\setminus\{e\}$", it is clear that the symbol is intended to be the set difference (not *symmetric* difference, @MAS). They specifically talk about group actions of $G$ on the underlying set of $H$ that are not automorphisms.

Comment: Any group has an underlying set, and by abuse of notation we often refer to both the group and its underlying set with the same symbol. (George Bergman is the only modern author I know who is very careful about distinguishing the two, in his "Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions"). So here, even though both $\mathrm{Sym}(H)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ are groups, the symbols also represent the underlying sets of those groups, and as such all of the usual group operations apply. The same way we sometimes write "$H\cup K$" to talk about the set-theoretic union of two subgroups.

Comment: Tx @ArturoMagidin,  so basically $\phi_g$ Is any bijection which Is not an automorphism of $H$. Not really clear why basing an action on It, but that's yet another problem.

Comment: @riccardoventrella  ...associated to a specific element $g\in G$, because we are letting $G$ act on $H$ via actions-that-are-not-automorphisms.

Comment: Yes, as the OP of the linked post, I confirm: I meant the set difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every automorphism of $H$ permutes the elements of $H$, so can be considered an element of $\mbox{Sym}(H)$, but not every permutation of elements of $H$ is (induced by) an automorphism.